# How can I electively ignore a knockout 'submit' binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a form with the knockout binding `data-bind="submit: saveProfileChanges"`. The viewmodel function `saveProfileChanges` calls into the following new code:

```
dataAccess.submitJsonWithFileRequestjQueryWithErrorFunction = function () {
    function uploadImageComplete() {
        // Hanlde response from image post.
    }
    $("#upload_iframe").load(function() {
        uploadImageComplete();
    });
    $("#userProfileForm").submit();
};
```

I have added this code to allow a pseudo-ajax image upload for IE9, using the iframe fallback. I have tried jquery plugins for this upload without success and decided a plain and simple approach would be less risky and minimise impact on loads of functionality I am not aware of.

The problem is now the `submit` call in my upload method triggers the ko bound `saveProfileChanges`, which calls my upload function again, ad-nauseum. Is there a way I can ignore the ko binding for just my local call to `submit`? My less savouryu alternative is to set a flag in my viewmodel while busy doing an upload, so `saveProfileChanges` will simply return without doing anything further, until my upload finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a jQuery issue rather than KO. Change your submission call to:

```
$("#userProfileForm")[0].submit();
// Change -----------^^^
```

E.g., call the `form` element's `submit` rather than jQuery's. The `form` element's function *won't* fire the `submit` event again, but jQuery's will.

I take it that your form submission is happening after some asynchronous task (like uploading a file), since otherwise you'd just want to have `saveProfileChanges` return `true` to tell KO to allow the default action (since KO will default to automatically preventing the submission).

Here's a demonstration of the issue with using jQuery's `submit`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/poxime/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="kittens">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  // Hook a handler to the form's submit event. Note that KO will
  // use jQuery to do this if jQuery is on the page, so we'll do it
  // via jQuery
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    var form = this;

    // Note that we got the event
    ++counter;
    display("submit event received, counter = " + counter);

    // Simulate asynchronous task
    setTimeout(function() {
      // We limit the number of times we'll re-fire
      if (counter < 3) {
        alert("submitting form using jQuery's submit function (counter = " + counter + ")");
        $(form).submit();
      } else {
        alert("but now we'll submit it directly, not through jQuery");
        form.submit();
      }
    }, 10);

    // By default, KO will prevent the default, so do that
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ProfK: I figured (about the async). Using the DOM `HTMLFormElement#submit` rather than jQuery's should sort it out. The other sounds like it's a different problem -- good luck!